# codeigniter validation - error message if key is not sent

Tags: php, forms, api, codeigniter, validation

I am new to codeigniter.

Have a doubt in form validation... I am doing a rest api project using codeigniter. 
In that I have to validate the input data.

If i send `user_name` key with value or empty... the `form_validation` library throws an error that field is required.

But it is not showing.. anything.. if I am not sending the `user_name` key itself...

If the key is not there, library should also throw the required error message.. right ?

Example

for example:

```
example.com/?user_name=test
Error Message : Success

example.com/?user_name=
Error Message : User name is required

example.com/
Error Message : [EMPTY]
```

Now it should say User name is required .. .right...

How to set this rule... using codeigniter `form_validation` library.. ?

Is this clear?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself.

Comment: I have updated.. Please check...
and let me know, 

thanks

Comment: Please post some relevant code here (Controller, View... etc.)

Comment: `$this->form_validation->set_rules("user_name", "Username", "required|min_length[5]|max_length[10]|alpha_numeric|is_unique[lm_users.user_name]");`

**This code returns username is required when the user_name parameter is passed empty. But if there is no user_name parameter, it is not showing the validation error**

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter does in fact need all input fields that are in your validation rules passed to the processing script or it will fail and not return errors. (I don't like it either)